# TypeError: User is not a constructor on adding data to model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node js and mongoose. I was just trying to create a db and add data to it.
I have users.js where I have connected to db and created a schema.

users.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    // make a connection 
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/login_details', { useNewUrlParser: true });

    // get reference to database
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log("Connection Successful!");

        // define Schema
        var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: String,
          username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
          password: { type: String, required: true }
        });

        // compile schema to model
        var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

    // a document instance
    module.exports = {User};
});
```

In test.js I am trying to create a new user.

test.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var User = require("./users");
//Load all your models
//var User = require('./users');

// create a new user called chris
var saps = new User({
  name: 'Midoriya',
  username: 'deku',
  password: 'password'
});


// call the built-in save method to save to the database
saps.save(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('User saved successfully!');
});
```

On executing test.js I am getting following error.

```
var saps = new User({
           ^

TypeError: User is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sapan/nodejsdev/websocket-test/test.js:7:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get this out of the `db.once` context:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

// compile schema to model
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Since you are defining them there they are local to that context and not available in any other.

Comment: Makes sense. But the issue still persists

Comment: Also can you `module.exports = User;` instead of `module.exports = {User};`

Comment: That did it !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. It turned out that I typed

```
mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

instead of:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

That's what it's all about!